# package restore failed rolling back package change for ' myproject' in vs 2017 .net mvc core project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

package restore failed rolling back package change for ' my project' in vs 2017 .net MVC core project while updating packages

Comment: This question is poorly worded (no question is asked) and does not provide much information ... did you just add a new package ? what's the context ?

Comment: please describe your problem, environment and what you have tried so far to fix it

Comment: Hi, did find solution around this matter? if not try, tools--> option--> NuGet Package Manager--> Click 'Clear all Nuget Cache(s)' and that should do the trick.

Comment: Visit this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45906856/package-restore-failed-rolling-back-package-changes/46144314#46144314

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. Created a new app ASP.Net Core(.Net Framework). And wanted to add the library, but faced the error. When trying to update the same problem.
[image][image]

**FIXED**

The solution was simple. When creating the project I chose ASP.NET CORE v 1. After rebuilding the project ASP.NET CORE v 2, it worked.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the "packages" folder in your solution and all the projects and colse-reopen Visual Studio