# Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

When I am trying to install any nuget package in VS2017 for asp.net core. it is constantly showing "Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes" for each package.

Comment: Unless you post the exact error message we can't help you. It usually comes, when you try to add/download a package which is not supported by your platform

Comment: "Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes" it's right there

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error : Package restore failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44509694/error-package-restore-failed)

Answer (score 48):

You can do the following steps:

1. VS Tools
2. Options
3. Nuget Package Manager
4. General
5. **Clear All Nuget Cache(s)**.

**OR**

You need to change target .net core 1.1 to 2.0, and this is possible if you update your VS 2017 with the **latest version(ex. VS 2017 15.3)**

[image]

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem. Mine still fails after doing this.

Comment: Is there an error log where we can view the output?

Comment: Is that the same as Clear All Nuget Storage? (2022)

Comment: I get messages "NuGet cache(s) clear failed at 7.10.2023 13:20:28. 
Error: Clearing local resources failed: Unable to delete one or more files.
Please see https://aka.ms/troubleshoot_nuget_cache for more help."

Answer (score 18):

Interestingly, I faced the same problem in .net5 and Visual Studio 2019 v16.9.4, the code generation design package had a version of `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design v5.0.2`.

After some digging I found out that scaffolding was trying to install a version of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` that was older than the one I already depend on. Which was `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer v5.0.5` so I downgraded its version to v5.0.4 and tried again after clearing nuget cache and it worked! After done scaffolding I then upgraded dependencies back to the desired version that I want.

Comment: This was the solution in my case as well- I had to downgrade all my EF Core NuGet packages to v5.0.4 in a related project that the UI project had a dependency on. Then everything scaffolded correctly.

Comment: I have downgraded 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' NuGet package from V5.0.13 to V5.0.12 and now i can generate razor pages. Thanks...

Comment: This is still happening as of 3/13/22 with .NET 6.  For me, downgrading Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer from 6.0.3 to 6.0.2 allowed me to scaffold a new controller.

Answer (score 16):

You Simply need to  clear the NuGet Cache.
To do this ->

1. Go to Tools
2. Options
3. NuGet Package Manager
4. General
5. Clear All NuGet Cache(s)

Comment: Is that the same as Clear All Nuget Storage? (2022)

Answer (score 9):

If you are trying update to a dotnet core 2.0 package, you need change the target in .csproject file.

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: This solved the problem for me - was targeting Core 1.1, needed to change build target to 2.0 - thanks.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, i simply needed to update all already installed Nuget packages and then it started working.

Comment: In my case, VS2019 wants to install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer v5.0.11,  but I already installed and had it with v5.0.7.  So after I update it along with other packages to v5.0.11 and Clear All NuGet Cache(s) it works for me.

Comment: Using VS2022 and .Net 7 with razor pages. Same issue and this resolved it.

Answer (score 4):

[image]
Try to install the appropriate version of the .net framework which you want to target.

Right click on your project, go to Properties, and then **Install Other Frameworks**.

This will take you to the [TechNet download page for .netCore](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks?utm_source=getdotnetsdk&utm_medium=referral), download the appropriate SDK version here, install and then restart Visual Studio.

Now go back to Project Properties and pick the new Target Framework version and try again, it should work this time.

Answer (score 3):

I just install these packages and it worked

1. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
2. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
3. Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design

The version of the packages you install must be the same as your .Net or .NetCore version.

Answer (score 2):

bring the version of the solution package to 1.1.3
[nuget package Version 1.1.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72VcV.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Answer:
Add/update nuget package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design

Answer (score 2):

I am using VS2019 and `.net5`. When I tried to generate controllers and views, Nuget Package suddenly installed 3 packages:

- `EntityFrameworkCore.SQLserver`,
- `EntityFrameworkCore.Tools`,
- `Microsoft.VisualStudio.web.CodeGeneration.Design`

Also update all of them if there is any new version published. But before that I'd have installed the package `EntityFrameworkCore`. Its version is `5.0.15` as well as `SQLserver` and `Tools(5.0.15)`.The issue existed only when new version 5.0.16 released. When Scaffolding, VS try to update `SQLserver` and `Tools` to `5.0.16` but they were conflicted with `EntityFrameworkCore` package still in `5.0.15` resulted in:

> restored package failed

The solution is uninstall `EntityFrameWorkCore` package might help you or you can update it manually.

Answer (score 1):

**Update Nuget package
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer**

**it will resolved because while we using scaffolding for new controller then DbContext class object is created that why correct package is required to update for EntityFrameworkCore **

Comment: thanks very much this worked, i was using 6.0.26 for both, i updated to 6.0.27 and tried again and yes it worked. so relieved!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure! you do not use the same name of the project as the Dependency name you are going to install.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30286333)

Comment: This is true, if the pckage you are trying to install and your project name are same, you will get the same error. Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes. Cycle detected.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I named the project same as the plugin that i wanted to install cause this error.

for example:

My project is named `ScottPlot`, and error occur when i want to install the nuget package `ScottPlot`

Rename the project or recreate with different name will solve this error!

Answer (score 1):

This error happened in my dotnet 0.7 C# project. after trying out above solutions. it didn't resolve my case.

Then I followed the below steps, and the problem was solved:
1- I renamed my existing [ApplicationDBContext] into the solution to another name.
2- I uninstalled two packages using Nuget package manager.
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design
and
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Contracts

Eventually I called [add new]-> [New scaffolded Item]
in the pop-up screen, I selected
[Identity] from left panel, then I hit [New] button

It worked fine and I was able to collect all identity pages.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please specify which nuget package you are trying to install

As you have said you are getting the error

> Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes

once you get this msg open your output window. it will show all the packages it installed and where it has failed and started restoring. From there you will be able to debug it.

For people who are getting error for Microsoft.AspNetCore.All. 
please go to project>properties>application>target Framework.

The framework should be compatible with Microsoft.AspNetCore.All

Answer (score 0):

With VS2019 go to Project > Manage Nuget Packackes... and then check to see if there are any updates for your installed packages, running the updates fixed this for me.

Answer (score 0):

For mine it said that i just had to change the version in my .csproj file to "4.5.0.530."

So, I went to the .csproj file, if you don't know how to do so check out [this one minute video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zp1x44X5WtI), and after following the steps, you should come to a page that look something like this.

[image]

Change your Version to "4.5.0.530" on the first line (I already did that, but it was originally something like "4.9":

```
  <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="4.5.0.530 />
```

Then you can save the .csproj file and reload the project. 
Try and re-install the plugin again.

Answer (score 0):

I am in Visual Studio 2019. I have ContosoUniversity project running in .NET Core 5.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">  
<PropertyGroup>
<TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.12" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.12" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="5.0.12">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="5.0.2" />
</ItemGroup>

<Project>
```

The package restore error comes while scaffolding because of the conflict in versions. I created a new project from blank and then scaffolded a simple model, and then copied its dependencies version to my existing project and it worked.
The above code shows the version specifications that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this issue as well while developing a .NET 5 Web API.

The problem stemmed from when I was trying to allow Visual Studio to automatically install the latest version of the NuGet which was Version 6.0.0.

This obviously bombed out as my application was being built in .NET 5 and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.0 is only compatible with .NET 6 (VS 2022).

To fix, I just needed to verify that the version of EF Core I was installing was compatible with my current .NET version.

Answer (score 0):

in my case vs 2022 I update all the packages I already install it  and its worked

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSF3c.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me, I had to go to my .csproj file and directly reference the changes i want to make in there. For example:

FROM

```
<PackageReference Include="Amazon.Extensions.CognitoAuthentication" Version="2.2.2" />
```

TO

```
<PackageReference Include="Amazon.Extensions.CognitoAuthentication" Version="2.2.3" />
```

Then go to your NuGet package manager and install the updated version.

Answer (score 0):

**update xamarin.forms**

update xamarin.forms from NuGet managers and clear all NuGet caches

Answer (score 0):

Try using a lower version for the package you want to install I was getting the same error while installing jwtbearer in .net 7 Then I used '6.0.16' version of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authenciation.JwtBearer

Answer (score 0):

First, see your project Target Framework and install the same version of the NuGet package. I hope this is helpful

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

You should do following processes:

1. clear all entity frame work packages include: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore,
   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools,
   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
2. do scaffolding
3. install again all above entity frame work packages

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was multiple sources for the packages. In this instance I was using DevExtreme and had two local and one external sources.

Inside of Options > NuGet Package Manager > Package Sources

When I unchecked the two locals it fixed the error. Thereafter clean and rebuild the solution to double check. Hope this helps.[image]