# Couldn't Add NuGet Package

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

When I try to add the `Plugin.FirebasePushNotification` to my Xamarin.Android Project in Xamarin.Forms, I receive the following message, and the package isn't added.  It seems to work fine on the iOS and Shared Projects, however.  How would I fix this?

```
All packages and projects are compatible with MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0.
Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes
```

Message during Package Restore:

```
Version conflict detected for Xamarin.Android.Support.Collections. Install/reference Xamarin.Android.Support.Collections 28.0.0.3 directly to project Project.Android to resolve this issue. 
 Project.Android -> Project -> Plugin.FirebasePushNotification 3.3.10 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 28.0.0.3 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat 28.0.0.3 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.VersionedParcelable 28.0.0.3 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Collections (= 28.0.0.3) 
 Project.Android -> Project -> Xamarin.Auth 1.7.0 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs 28.0.0.1 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Collections (= 28.0.0.1).
Restore failed.
```

Comment: Have you tried clearing Nuget cache? You can do that by going to Tools -> Options... -> Nuget Packet Manager -> General -> Clear All Nuget Cache(s)

Comment: How would I do this on Visual Studio for Mac? Not seeing the option...

Comment: Also, when I try to restore my packages it says "Couldn't restore packages"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46144314/9733566

Comment: @ums2026 You could try to update all your packages like Xamarin.forms in NuGet. If it is possible, could you provide the details in your output window?

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT Xamarin.Forms is up to date.  They aren't really giving me much in the output window except what I have provided to be honest.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT added info for the error when restoring packages

Comment: @ums2026 What is the Android version of your target framework? Have you set it into Android 10.0?

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT Android version is 11.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by manually editing the .csproj file to include the packages as instructed in the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing NuGet cache via command line:

```
nuget locals all -clear
```

To setup `nuget` you can check **macOS/Linux** section of [NuGet CLI reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-exe-cli-reference).

Comment: Tried this, unfortunately didn't do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I might be a bit late to this but the solution is always the same:

Go to nuget -> updates.

Update xamarin.essentials and xamarin.forms. (actually, FORMS FIRST!).

then comand line:

```
nuget locals all -clear
```

And then it will work again.