# Error running the selected code generator in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-core

I keep getting this error when trying to add a scaffolded item to my presentation layer.

[image]

Packages I am using

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like scaffolding the items installing the older version of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` or `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` then your project currently depends on.

There are several ways that might help you fix the said issue. You could try them one by one.

1. Try to clear Nuget Cache.

- Go to Tools in the Visual Studio
- Options
- NuGet Package Manager
- General
- Clear All NuGet Cache(s)

2. If the issue persists, try to manually update the packages `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` or `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`
3. Try to update the rest of the NuGet packages.

Reference: [Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45906856/package-restore-failed-rolling-back-package-changes)

Comment: I tried to update them to a lower one to 3.1.19 and cleared the NuGet packages it still persists :(

Comment: If possible for you then for testing purposes, try to remove/uninstall `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` packages. Clear the NuGet package cache. Try to add a scaffolded item. see whether it adds the packages again without conflicting the versions of it.

Comment: This saved my day after loosing hours of trying and removing all possible versions manually. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For me even after choosing the latest version for  the packages which are same did not work. The work around of letting the framework to choose the version helped me to solve the issue. The idea by @Deepak-MSFT in the comments section helped. Just adding the details.

```
 1. Uninstalled the  all the packages.
 2. The error for DbContext was anyways thrown by IDE, tried to install the  using pressing Alt + Enter and let the IDE install the compatible version. 
 3. Tried to add the scoffolded item. This will again install the Tools with proper version. Then its up to you to decide  the version of SqlServer version by looking at the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore and other pakcages.
 
   For me 
   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore - 7.0.13
   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer - 7.0.13
   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools - 7.0.12
   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.CodeGeneration.Design- 7.0.11 worked
```