# ASP.NET Core 7 MVC error while scaffolding a Identity

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-7.0

I am building an ASP.NET Core 7 MVC application and I was going to add login and register functionality to my web app. Sadly, after trying to scaffold identity to the project, I get this error:

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkIf0.png).

Here is a github repo for this project:

[Here](https://github.com/RokasMesk/ConstructionManagementSystem)

I tried deleting BIN and OBJ folders, cleaning rebuilding solution... updating packages to the same version, nothing worked. I hope you have any ideas how to fix this.

Comment: See this link for help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71901574/error-running-the-selected-code-generator-in-visual-studio

Comment: Sadly didn't help

Answer (score 0):

> There was an error running the selected code generator: 'package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'ConstructionManagementSystem''

Based on the project you shared, to fix above issue, you can try:

*Step 1: install following package in project `ConstructionManagementSystem`*

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore --version 7.0.14`

*Step 2: then scaffold identity into your project*

[image]